# How to vary the colors within each facet panel as well as across different facet panels in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a plot like the one below created using `ggplot2`, which has three facet panels.

[image]

However, I would like to have, say two shades of red in the left panel, two shades of green in the middle panel, and two shades of blue in the right panel. So in other words, the two ribbons in each panel differ in their colors, and the colors between panels also differ. But I haven't figured out a way to do it. The code I used to obtain the code is below. `factor1` is a 2-level variable, and `factor2` is a 3-level variable. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = window, group=factor1)) + 
       facet_grid(.~factor2) + 
       geom_line(aes(y=fit), alpha=0.8, colour="gray20") + 
       geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=fit - 1.96*se, ymax=fit+1.96*se, fill=factor1), alpha=0.7) + 
       geom_vline(xintercept=0, colour="gray20") + 
       geom_vline(xintercept=4, colour="red", size=.1) +
       geom_hline(xintercept=0, colour="black",size=.1, linetype="dashed") + 
       theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour="black")) + 
       theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), 
             panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify variable interactions to vary colors. You need to define the color palette manually to get the shading you want:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = window, group=factor1)) + 
       facet_grid(.~factor2) + 
       geom_line(aes(y=fit), alpha=0.8, colour="gray20") + 
       geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=fit - 1.96*se, ymax=fit+1.96*se, fill=factor1:factor2), alpha=0.7) + 
       geom_vline(xintercept=0, colour="gray20") + 
       geom_vline(xintercept=4, colour="red", size=.1) +
       geom_hline(xintercept=0, colour="black",size=.1, linetype="dashed") + 
       theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour="black")) + 
       theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(), 
             panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I tried your solution, I got the following error messages: `Error in factor1:factor2 : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In factor1:factor2 :
  numerical expression has 480 elements: only the first used
2: In factor1:factor2 :
  numerical expression has 480 elements: only the first used
3: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: Ah, I got what the problem is. the level names in each factor - like "One vs. three". When I switched to simpler labels, the problem went away.

Comment: You beat me to it. If one factor has 2 levels and the other 3, you should get 6 levels from the interaction, not hundreds.

Comment: A follow-up question: the legend now shows all 6 conditions, but what I really want is for the 2-levels in factor 1 to be shown in the legend. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible. Take a look at the help for `guide_legend` and other questions here on SO.